# The Relationship between Reflexive Space, Separable Space and Compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology, reflexive-space

I'm currently studying Functional Analysis. I am confused about the relationship between reflexive spaces, separable spaces, and compactness of the unit ball (in different space, in different topology).

1. Does the compactness of the closed unit ball in $X^*$ in weak* topology related to $X$ separable? My teacher tolds us that if $X$ is separable, then for any bounded sequence $\{f_n\} \subset X^*$ it contains a converged subsequence. But Banach-Alaogu tells us that the unit ball in $X^*$ is closed in weak* topology.
2. How can we prove a space is reflexive? So far as I know, we can prove the uniform convexity property, or instead we can prove the unit ball in $X$ is precompact in weak topology. Are there other ways?
3. I'm thinking about the relationship between reflexive and separable. Are there any results about that? How can I understand the connection between them?

Comment: Ideally you should separate these into three questions.  Keep question 1 here, and post questions 2 and 3 separately.  If it helps you, provides links between the three :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The unit ball in the dual space $X^{*}$ is always compact under the weak$^{*}$ topology by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, however, recall that for a general topological space compactness and sequential compactness are not equivalent. If X is separable one can show (see for example Theorem 3.28 in Haim Brezis book) that the unit ball in the dual space is metrizable and hence also sequentially compact.
2. One can sometimes give an explicit characterization of the dual space, as in the case of $L^{p}$, for $1 < p < \infty$. There is also a result that says if $Y$ is a closed subspace of a reflexive space $X$, then $Y$ is reflexive.
3. I have no useful comments here.

Answer (score 1):

For 3:

If we take $X$ to be a set, we can define $\ell^2(X)$ to be the set of functions $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$
\| f \| = \sum_{x \in X} |f(x)|^2
$$
converges. This space $\ell^2(X)$ is a Hilbert space, and therefore is reflexive. Now, we can define the standard orthonormal basis $(e_x)_{x \in X}$ to have $e_x(x) = 1$ and $e_x(y) = 0$ for $y \in X$ with $y \neq x$. If $x,y \in X$ are different, then $\| e_x - e_y \| = 2$. So $\{e_x\}_{x \in X}$ is a discrete subset of $\ell^2(X)$.

Now, take $X$ to be your favourite uncountable set. Then $\{e_x\}_{x \in X}$ is a discrete uncountable metric space, and therefore not separable. This proves that $\ell^2(X)$ is not separable, because subspaces of separable *metric* spaces are separable.